# Number theory, random task

Tags: number-theory

I have this pretty random task and I really don't where to begin. I hope that somebody would help me. The question is very simple:

Find the smallest positive integer, so when is took to the third exponent, its last    digits will be  ...888

Comment: Well. I know it's something about $$n^3 \equiv 888\ mod\ 1000$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a simpler task: finding numbers $n$ such that their cubes end with 8 in decimal. Clearly they need to be even, so let's look at 2, 4, 6, 8, and 10. Their cubes are 8, 64, 216, 512, and 1000 so only 2 worked. These are the only final digits that could work, so the numbers which have cubes ending with 8 are exactly those of the form $10n+2$.

Can you continue this process?

Comment: Only 9 works now so it's of the form $100n + 10 \cdot 9 +2$.       Now does only 1 works, so we have $100\cdot 1+ 10 \cdot 9 +2=192$. Is that correct?

Comment: @WilliamSidis: Well, 4 also works, so you have either $100n+42$ or $100n+92$. These lead to four possibilities mod 1000: 192, 442, 692, and 942. The least of these is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a bit less ambition: For which $n$ does $n^3$ end in $\ldots 8$? The last digit depends only on the last digti of $n$ and as you can check, this last digit must be $2$. So $n= 10k+2$ for some integer $k$.
Then $n^3=(10k+2)^3=1000k^3+600k^2+120k+8$ and we note that the tens digit of $n^3$ is the ones digit of $2k$. To make this equal $8$, we must have $2k=10m+8$ or equivalently $k=5m+4$ for some integer $m$, so that $n=10k+2=50m+42$. Expand $n^3=(50m+42)^3$ as above and make a similar conclusion about the last digit of $m$, thus finding an expression for *all* integers $n$ such that $n^3$ ends in $888$.

Comment: Excuse me, but how do "we note that the tens digit of n^3 is the ones digit of 2k"